# iTextSharp - Bug in the table functions?

Tags: itext

I try to make a table like this:

```
PdfPTable Table = new PdfPTable(6);

PdfPCell Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("a", Font1));
Cell.Rowspan = 2;
Cell.Colspan = 2;
Table.AddCell(Cell);

Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("b", Font1));
Cell.Rowspan = 2;
Cell.Colspan = 2;
Table.AddCell(Cell);

Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("c", Font1));
Cell.Colspan = 2;
Table.AddCell(Cell);

Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("d", Font1));
Cell.Colspan = 2;
Table.AddCell(Cell);
```

That works fine. But changing the number of columns will destory the table. Is it a bug or do I make something wrong?

This code destroys the table:

```
PdfPTable Table = new PdfPTable(17);

PdfPCell Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("a", Font1));
Cell.Rowspan = 2;
Cell.Colspan = 2;
Table.AddCell(Cell);

Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("b", Font1));
Cell.Rowspan = 2;
Cell.Colspan = 10;
Table.AddCell(Cell);

Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("c", Font1));
Cell.Colspan = 5;
Table.AddCell(Cell);

Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("d", Font1));
Cell.Colspan = 5;
Table.AddCell(Cell);
```

Edit: The table should have this layout:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Cell "a" with | Cell "b" with | Cell "c", colspan = 5 |
| colspan = 2   | colspan = 10  |-----------------------|
| rowspan = 2   | rowspan = 2   | Cell "d", colspan = 5 |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: The total `colspan` is greater than the column argument in the `PdfPTable` constructor... why is that?

Comment: The table should have 2 columns on the left with a rownspan of 2. Right of these 2 cells there should be 2 cells below each other.
So the 2 right cells must have the same colspan and the total colspan number is greater than the number of columns of the table.

I think this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Table.CompleteRow();` as last line.